# Change docker storage driver on Mac OS X

Tags: docker, docker-machine

I installed the docker toolbox on my Mac OS X and I need to change the docker storage driver from *aufs* to *devicemapper*, because *aufs* causing problems.

I found the [offical documentations of docker](https://docs.docker.com/engine/userguide/storagedriver/selectadriver/) and tried it the way explained [here](http://muehe.org/posts/switching-docker-from-aufs-to-devicemapper/), but `DOCKER_OPTS="--storage-driver=devicemapper"` doesn't work for me.

`docker info` still tells me `Storage Driver: aufs`.

I didn't managed to find the file located at `/etc/default/docker` as well.

For the record, I need to changed it in order to run [CodeClimate CLI](https://github.com/codeclimate/codeclimate) properly.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Change storage driver for Docker on OS X](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39455764/change-storage-driver-for-docker-on-os-x)

Answer (score 2):

You can use the `--engine-storage-driver` flag when you create a new VM with docker-machine to choose a storage driver.

```
$ docker-machine create -d virtualbox \
    --engine-storage-driver devicemapper \
    foobarmachine
```

[docs reference](https://docs.docker.com/machine/reference/create/)

Comment: I tried it that way before, but the creation of the machine fails: http://pastebin.com/Sw3WStML

Answer (score 0):

> Modifying the storage-driver is not supported on Docker Desktop for Mac and Docker Desktop for Windows, and only the default storage driver can be used.

[Docker documentation](https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/select-storage-driver/)