# Change storage driver for Docker on OS X

Tags: macos, docker, osx-elcapitan

This is basically a follow-up [to this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36845691/change-docker-storage-driver-on-mac-os-x), but now since the OS X Docker no longer needs Docker Toolbox (i.e. no longer needs VirtualBox), I'm totally lost how to switch from `AUFS` to `devicemapper` or something else.

The issue I'm facing here as well is [the missing hardlink support](https://github.com/docker/docker/issues/4570#issuecomment-44360438) in `AUFS` which makes problems during the installation of the Android SDK, so I hope `devicemapper` will help me here.

So, how can I change the storage driver of Docker's native implementation in OS X?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

The Alpine Linux VM that Docker for Mac runs doesn't support the `devicemapper` driver but it can run the `overlay2` driver.

<strike>There's no UI for managing this config yet</strike> The Docker for Mac UI has been updated to include a "Daemon" section where you can edit the `docker.json` config file.

Got to the Docker icon > "Preferences" > "Daemon" > "Advanced" and set the `storage-driver` to `overlay2`

```
{ "storage-driver": "overlay2" }
```

See [kojiros](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42230166/1318694) answer for full step by step details.

#### Manual Config Editing

You [can modify the Docker config](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39264037/1318694) files on your mac in `~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/database`.

This directory is a git repo and it will normally be blank:

```
$ cd ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/database
$ ls -al
total 0
drwxr-xr-x   4 user  staff  136 28 Sep 02:46 .
drwxr-xr-x  20 user  staff  680 28 Sep 02:54 ..
drwxr-xr-x  11 user  staff  374 28 Sep 02:58 .git
```

There are files in the git database though

```
$ git status
On branch master
Changes not staged for commit:
  (use "git add/rm <file>..." to update what will be committed)
  (use "git checkout -- <file>..." to discard changes in working directory)

    deleted:    com.docker.driver.amd64-linux/etc/docker/daemon.json
    deleted:    com.docker.driver.amd64-linux/etc/hostname
    deleted:    com.docker.driver.amd64-linux/etc/sysctl.conf
....
```

To retrieve the previous contents from git, run:

```
$ git reset --hard HEAD
```

Edit the docker daemon config file that now exists, to include the `overlay2` storage driver.

```
$ vi com.docker.driver.amd64-linux/etc/docker/daemon.json
```

Docker on the VM will need most of `/var/lib/docker` removed before you can start with a new storage driver. This will *DELETE* all of your containers, images and volumes! Take backups of anything you need beforehand.

Attach to the VM's tty with `screen` (`brew install screen` if you don't have it)

```
$ screen ~/Library/Containers/com.docker.docker/Data/com.docker.driver.amd64-linux/tty
```

Login with `root`, no password

```
moby:~# /etc/init.d/docker stop
moby:~# rm -rf /var/lib/docker/*
```

Exit the prompt with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>d</kbd>

Exit the screen session with <kbd>ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>a</kbd> then <kbd>d</kbd>

Now you can commit your changes back on the mac

```
$ git commit -m overlay com.docker.driver.amd64-linux/etc/docker/daemon.json
```

Changes will be picked up automatically by Docker on commit and the VM will be restarted.

You now have a Docker for Mac VM running with the `overlay2` storage driver. If that doesn't resolve your problems, with some work you could probably figure out how to get `devicemapper` support working in the VM too. The steps once you've figured that out are all the same.

**Note** Upgrades to Docker for Mac can cause some weirdness. Last upgrade all my containers/images disappeared from a `docker ps` or `docker images`. I had to reset the git repository again and restart Docker for my config changes to come back, then all the data came back.

Comment: Ah perfect, thanks a lot! I'll try this out. Since I worked around the hardlink issue in the meantime, I still have another issue with Docker-for-Mac, poor I/O performance on mapped volumes (https://github.com/docker/for-mac/issues/77). Is a change in the driver here eventually helping out as well?

Comment: No, if you are mounting volumes from osx they are stuck using osxfs, no matter what the storage driver is in docker. That http://docker-sync.io/ tool looks useful though, saves writing your own rsync setup.

Comment: Actually http://docker-sync.io does not only offer rsync setups, but also 2-way-transparent syncs using unison+unox able to cope with 50k files+

Comment: Upvoted because your first sentence is useful, but now the UI does offer a better way to change daemon options. Please see [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42230166/418413) for details.

Comment: Current docker "edge" (17.07.0-ce-rc2-mac22 (18909)) reports that `"storage-driver" : Cannot be used in Docker for Mac`. It seems that `overlay2` is the default now and thus the setting is no longer accepted :)

Answer (score 11):

Matt is correct that the default Docker-for-Mac kernel doesn't support devicemapper, but in general, there's a better way to change the daemon options:

Start Docker for Mac.
Click the whale in the menu bar, then click Preferences

[image: the docker whale menu, with the preferences option highlighted]

Click [image: the Daemon icon in Docker for Mac Preferences]

Click Advanced and provide the JSON for customizing your daemon settings.

[image: The Docker Preferences Dialog under Daemon/Advanced]

Then click Apply & Restart, and check the change:

```
$ docker info | grep Stor
Storage Driver: overlay2
```

Comment: Before using this method consider to remove all existing containers and images, otherwise they won't be listed and your disk will be full of orphan images.
`docker rm $(docker ps -a -q)` and `docker rmi -f $(docker images -a -q)`

Answer (score 0):

This has changed over time and the preceding answers are no longer correct.
2022-03-12
https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/select-storage-driver/
"Modifying the storage-driver is not supported on Docker Desktop for Mac"