# How to add jenkins user to docker startup options on a Mac?

Tags: docker

I need to add the following to the list of Docker startup arguments on my Mac:

```
-G jenkins
```

Does anyone know where on Mac OS X is the Docker configuration file?

Comment: Maybe /Library/Preferences/org.jenkins-ci

Comment: where are you running the jenkins that needs access?

Comment: See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/39737553/1318694) for where the config lives.. but I don't think that will help you connect your jenkins as there is no jenkins user in the Docker Linux VM.

Comment: Depending on where you are running Jenkins, [socat might help](https://integratedcode.us/2016/04/08/user-namespaces-sharing-the-docker-unix-socket/)

Comment: I;m running jenkins locally on my mac

Answer (score 0):

I have migrated my jenkins server to Linux, where it was very obvious where the docker config file is to be found.