# Mount point not found

Tags: docker, docker-for-windows, docker-desktop

I am running a Java EE 7 application (with a lot of classes) on WildFly with Jackson, CDI, Swagger and Drools. I think that this error originated when I started using Drools, however I am not certain. As there is no reference to a local class, I have no idea where the error originated.

AFAIK, the application works without problems, but when I deploy the application, I get the following error:

```
ERROR java.io.IOException: Mount point not found
ERROR   at sun.nio.fs.LinuxFileStore.findMountEntry(LinuxFileStore.java:91)
ERROR   at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileStore.<init>(UnixFileStore.java:65)
ERROR   at sun.nio.fs.LinuxFileStore.<init>(LinuxFileStore.java:44)
ERROR   at sun.nio.fs.LinuxFileSystemProvider.getFileStore(LinuxFileSystemProvider.java:51)
ERROR   at sun.nio.fs.LinuxFileSystemProvider.getFileStore(LinuxFileSystemProvider.java:39)
ERROR   at sun.nio.fs.UnixFileSystemProvider.getFileStore(UnixFileSystemProvider.java:368)
ERROR   at java.nio.file.Files.getFileStore(Files.java:1461)
ERROR   at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.FilePersistenceUtils.getPosixAttributes(FilePersistenceUtils.java:124)
ERROR   at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.FilePersistenceUtils.createTempFileWithAttributes(FilePersistenceUtils.java:112)
ERROR   at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.FilePersistenceUtils.writeToTempFile(FilePersistenceUtils.java:99)
ERROR   at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.ConfigurationFilePersistenceResource.doCommit(ConfigurationFilePersistenceResource.java:55)
ERROR   at org.jboss.as.controller.persistence.AbstractFilePersistenceResource.commit(AbstractFilePersistenceResource.java:58)
ERROR   at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl$4.commit(ModelControllerImpl.java:789)
ERROR   at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeDoneStage(AbstractOperationContext.java:743)
ERROR   at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.processStages(AbstractOperationContext.java:680)
ERROR   at org.jboss.as.controller.AbstractOperationContext.executeOperation(AbstractOperationContext.java:370)
ERROR   at org.jboss.as.controller.OperationContextImpl.executeOperation(OperationContextImpl.java:1329)
ERROR   at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.internalExecute(ModelControllerImpl.java:400)
ERROR   at org.jboss.as.controller.ModelControllerImpl.execute(ModelControllerImpl.java:222)
ERROR   at org.jboss.as.controller.remote.ModelControllerClientOperationHandler$ExecuteRequestHandler.doExecute(ModelControllerClientOperationHandler.java:208)
ERROR   at org.jboss.as.controller.remote.ModelControllerClientOperationHandler$ExecuteRequestHandler.access$300(ModelControllerClientOperationHandler.java:130)
ERROR   at org.jboss.as.controller.remote.ModelControllerClientOperationHandler$ExecuteRequestHandler$1$1.run(ModelControllerClientOperationHandler.java:152)
ERROR   at org.jboss.as.controller.remote.ModelControllerClientOperationHandler$ExecuteRequestHandler$1$1.run(ModelControllerClientOperationHandler.java:148)
ERROR   at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
ERROR   at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422)
ERROR   at org.jboss.as.controller.AccessAuditContext.doAs(AccessAuditContext.java:149)
ERROR   at org.jboss.as.controller.remote.ModelControllerClientOperationHandler$ExecuteRequestHandler$1.execute(ModelControllerClientOperationHandler.java:148)
ERROR   at org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.AbstractMessageHandler$ManagementRequestContextImpl$1.doExecute(AbstractMessageHandler.java:363)
ERROR   at org.jboss.as.protocol.mgmt.AbstractMessageHandler$AsyncTaskRunner.run(AbstractMessageHandler.java:472)
ERROR   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
ERROR   at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
ERROR   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
ERROR   at org.jboss.threads.JBossThread.run(JBossThread.java:320)
```

I am using **Docker Desktop for Windows**. Can anyone help me out where to look for a solution, where this error is coming from?

Comment: I found this bugreport; https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8165852 which was pointing me to the docker container that I am running. I tried the same deployment without docker, and the error disappeared.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This error is caused by the docker container you are running this application in. Look at the bug report here:

https://bugs.openjdk.java.net/browse/JDK-8165852

Comment: there is a [workaround](https://issues.jboss.org/browse/WFCORE-2301) being worked on as JDK issue is marked as `tbd_major` (which means that the next version -- 10 -- _may_ contain it). This should be available in the next Wildfly release (11).

Answer (score 8):

I had this error in the last days using the elasticsearch docker image in Docker for Mac. I have fixed the issue change the storage driver from overlay2 to aufs (not sure yet about the real impact of this change). You can change the store driver:

- Docker preferences
- Daemon tab
- Advanced tab
- Edit the json like this:

  {
    "storage-driver" : "aufs"
  }

I hope it helps you

Comment: thanks works! same issue here Docker for Mac (17.03.1-ce-mac12 (17661)). Docker docs describes AUFS as less performant in some cases.

Comment: Glad to help you

Comment: Be advised that after doing this you will lose your images and containers, use docker save before it.

Comment: I got this error in Ubuntu Linux also, you have to add this line: `{ "storage-driver" : "aufs" }` in `/etc/docker/daemon.json` and restart the docker service. Be careful with the previously built images because all of them will be lost, you should do a commit of the important ones before.

Answer (score 3):

We ran into the same issue, when running a custom elasticsearch container on OS X. The container was built on `docker.elastic.co/elasticsearch/elasticsearch:5.3.0`. However, the container started up cleanly on a similar environment, which seemed suspicious.

The problem was finally resolved, when we noticed that `docker info` showed different storage drivers for us. AUFS seems to work, where as overlay2 does not. [It can be changed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39455764/change-storage-driver-for-docker-on-os-x), but you will have to refetch and rebuild your current containers.

Comment: The issue was on a Windows machine in my case. So this is (1) not OS X specific or (2) an entirely different issue.

Comment: Did you check whether you can change the storage type, though? Docker for mac seems to run a linux-based virtual machine as an intermediate layer, and AFAIK that is where the storage engine is set.

Comment: for me, the worst part was that i mis-diagnosed by looking at an earlier error in the stacktrace: Caused by: java.io.IOException: failed to obtain lock on /usr/share/elasticsearch/data/nodes/0.
so started playing with docker volumes and user id 1000, until i realized the main reason was Caused by: java.io.IOException: Mount point not found.
after that and this answer, changing storage to aufs solved it (lubuntu and osx)

Answer (score 2):

I had the same error `ERROR java.io.IOException: Mount point not found`
 and was caused by an previous deployment process error from my application.

`PARSE: org.jboss.msc.service.StartException in service jboss.deployment.unit."my app.war".PARSE: WFLYSRV0153: Failed to process phase PARSE of deployment "myapp.war"  at...
...
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: WFLYEE0040: A component named 'ExampleEJB' is already defined in this module`

I suppose that because of the deployment error docker fails to (execute `ADD` and/or `CMD` command) copy the application files and to add them to the filesystem of the image.

```
Dockerfile
```

`ADD ./deployments /wildfly/standalone/deployments
...
 CMD ["/wildfly/bin/standalone.sh", ..., "--debug"]`

In my case solving the application error fixed the mount point exception.

Also I'm quite new in docker world so any suggestions are welcomed.