# Hypercorn with "--reload" and Docker volumes

Tags: python, docker, docker-compose, hypercorn

I am running Hypercorn with `--reload` inside a Docker container. The file I am running is kept in a volume managed by Docker Compose.

When I change the file on my system, I can see that the change is reflected in the volume, e.g. with `docker compose exec myapp /bin/cat /app/runtime/service.py`.

However, when I change a file in this way, Hypercorn does not restart as I would have expected. Is there some adverse interaction between Hypercorn and the Docker volume? Or am I expecting something from the `--reload` option that I should not expect?

Example files are below. My expectation was that modifying `runtime/service.py` from outside the container would trigger Hypercorn to restart the server with the modified version of the file. But this does not occur.

Edit: I should add that I am using Docker 20.10.5 via Docker Desktop for Mac, on MacOS 10.14.6.

Edit 2: This might be a Hypercorn bug. If I add `uvicorn[standard]` in `requirements.txt` and run `python -m uvicorn --reload --host 0.0.0.0 --port 8001 service:app`, the reloading works fine. Possibly related: https://gitlab.com/pgjones/hypercorn/-/issues/185

`entrypoint.sh`:

```sh
#!/bin/sh
cd /app/runtime
/opt/venv/bin/python -m hypercorn --reload --bind 0.0.0.0:8001 service:app
```

`Dockerfile`:

```
FROM $REDACTED

RUN /opt/venv/bin/python -m pip install -U pip
RUN /opt/venv/bin/pip install -U setuptools wheel

COPY requirements.txt /app/requirements.txt
RUN /opt/venv/bin/pip install -r /app/requirements.txt

COPY requirements-dev.txt /app/requirements-dev.txt
RUN /opt/venv/bin/pip install -r /app/requirements-dev.txt

COPY entrypoint.sh /app/entrypoint.sh

EXPOSE 8001/tcp

CMD ["/app/entrypoint.sh"]
```

`docker-compose.yml`:

```yaml
version: "3.8"
services:
  api:
    container_name: api
    hostname: myapp
    build:
      context: .
    ports:
      - 8001:8001
    volumes:
      - ./runtime:/app/runtime
```

`runtime/service.py`:

```py
import logging
import quart

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO)

app = quart.Quart(__name__)

@app.route('/')
async def handle_hello():
    logger.info('Handling request.')
    return 'Hello, world!\n'

@app.route('/bad')
async def handle_bad():
    logger.critical('Bad request.........')
    raise RuntimeError('Oh no!!!')
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is a minimal, fully working example which *does* auto-reload using `hypercorn`:

**`docker-compose.yaml`**

```yaml
services:
  app:
    build: .
    # Here --reload is used which works as intended!
    command: hypercorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8080 --reload src:app
    ports:
      - 8080:8080
    volumes:
      - ./src:/app/src
```

**`Dockerfile`**

```
FROM python:3.10-slim-bullseye
WORKDIR /app                                                          
RUN pip install hypercorn==0.14.3 quart==0.18.0
COPY src ./src
EXPOSE 8080
ENV QUART_APP=src:app
# This is the production command; docker-compose.yaml overwrites it for local development
CMD hypercorn --bind 0.0.0.0:8080 src:app
```

**`src/__init__.py`**

```py
from quart import Quart

app=Quart(__name__)

@app.route('/', methods=['GET'])
def get_root():
    return "Hello world!"
```

Run via `docker-compose up` and notice how `hypercorn` reloads once `__init__.py` got modified.

Answer (score 0):

You likely need to use a [volume mount](https://docs.docker.com/storage/volumes/#use-a-volume-with-docker-compose) to get the reload functionality!

This is because when you build the container, it bakes whatever you have locally into it. Further changes only affect your local filesystem.

---

This is arguably not intended-use (as the container becomes dependent on external files!), but likely useful for faster testing/debugging

You could also directly edit the container by connecting to it, which you may find suits your needs.

Comment: I am already using a volume in the Docker Compose file with `volumes: [./runtime:app/runtime]`. Are you saying I should use a named volume instead?

Comment: Oh, learns me for not reading your post properly; I'd first check that files put in the volume are really going where you expect and do appear in the container (maybe directly inspect the container for this) .. if they're not, get that happy first, otherwise you may need to change your storage driver to enable whatever feature the reloading is relying on to detect changes https://docs.docker.com/storage/storagedriver/select-storage-driver/

Comment: Thanks. I did confirm that the files are where they should be and are updating in sync. Unfortunately I am using Docker Desktop for Mac and cannot modify the storage driver. Perhaps this is the problem?

Comment: very likely; you should be able to use a custom config still to change it https://stackoverflow.com/a/39737553/4541045

Comment: I tried it with Uvicorn (as with `pip install uvicorn[standard]`), and it worked fine. This appears to be a Hypercorn-specific problem, possibly a bug.

Comment: that seems plausible - the code in question appears to be here! https://github.com/pgjones/hypercorn/blob/93e3c08c54c6de5ffdaaaed4e1b97aab4fcb7656/src/hypercorn/utils.py#L125 if you want to experiment

Comment: Related issue from the Hypercorn bug tracker: https://gitlab.com/pgjones/hypercorn/-/issues/185

Comment: Running into the very same issue, using latest `quart==0.18.0` w/ `hypercorn==0.14.3`. Auto reload isn't working when running this stack in a docker container, although volume/directory is mounted properly in the container. Reported here: https://github.com/pgjones/hypercorn/issues/83